# tag:[composer] install dependency error error [php7.0]

Tags: composer-php, php-7.0

Nothing to install, update or remove
Package swiftmailer/swiftmailer is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use symfony/mailer instead.
Package yii2tech/ar-softdelete is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Package zendframework/zend-escaper is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-escaper instead.
Package zendframework/zend-stdlib is abandoned, you should avoid using it. Use laminas/laminas-stdlib instead.

the above error should not appear while running composer install

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What kind of "error" do you refer to? The text you've shared is a notice about deprecated packages. Feel free to replace them, or ignore that notice

Comment: _"the above error should not appear while running composer install"_ have you checked the command-line options? Composer can suppress the output normally with the `--quiet` flag, consult your shells' user manual, it should give you more options to control command output.